# fwrite unformated data writes un expected interger?

Tags: c, file

Fwrite unformated data writes un expected interger? please help me to understand why i am getting 90 in below code?

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   int main()
{ 
    int i=12345;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("data","w");
    fprintf(fp,"%d",i);// 12345 good 
    fwrite(&i,4,1,fp);// why 90? i am aspecting 12345 in file data?
    fwrite(0,4,1,fp);//12345 good
}
```

Comment: You're writing binary data, why would you expect to see 12345 in the file?

Comment: I don't understand `fwrite(0,4,1,fp);` - shouldn't that crash?

Comment: @Drew McGowen  `fwrite(0,4,1,fp);` which attempts to dereference `0`. C does not specify that it should crash for it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @chux technically, yes, but more than likely it'll just crash (I'm making assumptions based on the observed output)

Comment: @Drew McGowen Agree about the likelihood.  The most insidious problem with UB is when is does not behave as badly as expected when expected.  (Like when it shows up _after_ product release.)

Answer (score 4):

`fwrite` is writing the raw bytes that represent the integer 12345 to your file.

Assuming `int` is 32 bits, this number is `0x00003039` in hex. Assuming a little-endian platform, this writes out the bytes `0x39`, `0x30`, `0x00`, `0x00`. Assuming ASCII encoding, `0x39` is the ASCII code for the character `'9'`, and `0x30` for the character `'0'`, thus you see `90` in your file.

The other two `0x00` bytes are either being ignored or replaced with spaces by whatever you're using to visualize the file.

Comment: but if i change int i from 12345 to 2345 then garbage why?

Comment: Depends on what the hex value of `i` is, and what character each byte represents. You can look up the ASCII table to see how a byte translates to a character.